# Regexes for validating & formatting numbers with different decimal delimiters

Tags: regex, numbers, delimiter, substitution

I'm trying to construct a regex to validate and capture numbers that can have either a comma or a dot as delimiter. After validation i want to output the formatted number using substitution.

This is my input and desired output (or at least enough to show my case):

```
,1 -> no match  
.1 -> no match  
1   -> 1  
10   -> 10  
10,5 -> 10,5  
333,5 -> no match  
5,555 -> no match  
10.50 -> 10,50  ( optimal output would be: 10,5 but not a requirement )  
blabla 10.5 blabla -> 1,5
```

with a maximum of 2 digits on both sides of the delimiter..

I use the following regex for validation:

```
^.*(?<!\S)(\d{1,2})(?:([\,\.])(\d{1,2}))?(?!\S).*$
```

the substitution regex below obviously doesn't work since numbers with no decimals would be wrong..

```
${number},${decimals}
```

can it be done with only 1 test & 1 substitution regex ? i guess the whole thing needs a redo.. but how ? :)

Comment: which flavor of regex?

Comment: vks -> java.util.regex

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do:

```
(?<![\d,.])(\d{1,2})(?:[.,](\d{1,2}))?(?![\d,.])
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/fR5oJ0/2)

**Explanation**:

1. `(?<![\d,.])`: Should not be preceded by a number or a delimiter (EG: ',' or '.')
2. `(\d{1,2})`: One to two digits
3. `(?:[.,](\d{1,2}))?`: If there is a delimiter (EG: ',' or '.') there should be at least one to two digits after it
4. `(?![\d,.])`: Should not be followed by a digit or a delimiter (EG: ',' or '.')

**Edit**: I added the capturing groups. You will be able to get the number with the first match and the floating value with the second.

**UPDATE**: Dots are not escaped in a character classes anymore. (Thanks to @Tensibai)

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` in a character class

Comment: how can i output this with ONLY commas as delimiter ?

Comment: You have to get rid of the dot in the delimting part : `(?<![\d,.])\d{1,2}(?:[,]\d{1,2})?(?![\d,.])`

Comment: lol I see u misunderstood what i meant.. i want to capture the numbers with both commas and dots as delimiter and output them with only comma as delimiter.. hope that clarifies it

Comment: I saw you were using Java. I don't know if you can solve this problem with regexs only. Here is what I would try : http://ideone.com/sszRNx

Comment: Yami -> thnx for the effort :) the problem is that its part of a bigger solution where I only have a file where I specify a single test regex and a substitution..